# Spring MVC :how a form transfer an object to Controller?? Always 400 error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, http-status-code-400

When i try to access http://localhost:8080/XX/articles/addArticle
and submit the form, there is always a "400 BAD REQUEST" error.
i've tried to look up for the reason, all i got is that object transfered from the form is not as same type as my model(, which is an Article object? here). However, i don't think i really get it..

All codes are here, the config is all good.
Here are 2 models:
Article.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="article_inf")
public class Article {
    private int articleId;
    private String title;
    private User author;
    private String content;
    public Article() {
    }
    public Article(String title, User author, String content) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.content = content;
    }
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getArticleId() {
        return articleId;
    }
    public void setArticleId(int articleId) {
        this.articleId = articleId;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=User.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="author", referencedColumnName="userId", nullable=false)
    public User getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }
    public void setAuthor(User author) {
        this.author = author;
    }
    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
```

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="agri_user_inf")
public class User {
    private int userId;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String cellPhone;
    private List<Article> articles;
    public User() {
        articles = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    public User(String userName, String password, String cellPhone) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
        this.cellPhone = cellPhone;
    }
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getCellPhone() {
        return cellPhone;
    }
    public void setCellPhone(String cellPhone) {
        this.cellPhone = cellPhone;
    }
    @OneToMany(targetEntity=Article.class, mappedBy="author")
    public List<Article> getArticles() {
        return articles;
    }
    public void setArticles(List<Article> articles) {
        this.articles = articles;
    }
```

controller
ArticleController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("articles")
public class ArticleController {
    private ArticleDao articleDao;
    @Autowired
    public ArticleController(ArticleDao articleDao) {
        this.articleDao = articleDao;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="addArticle", method=GET)
    public String addArticle(ModelMap modelMap) {
        List<User> authors = userDao.getAllUsers();
        // add all authors
        modelMap.addAttribute("authors", authors);
        return "articles/addArticleForm";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="addArticle", method=POST)
    public String addArticle(Article article) {
        articleDao.addArticle(article);
        return "redirect:/articles";
    }
    // other code
```

my form addArticleForm.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        title: <input type="text" name="title"/><br/>
        author: <select name="author">
                <c:forEach items="${authors}" var="author">
                    <option value="${author}">${author.userName}</option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select>
            <br/>
        content: <input type="text" name="content"/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="add"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As far as I see, you're missing the url/action in your JSP file. After the user clicks the submit button to which url/action this request will be taken?

Comment: `<option value="${author}">${author.userName}</option>` so the submitted value of author will be the toString() of the author. There is no way to convert that to a value of type User. My advice: don't use your entities to represent what a form submits. Use a dedicated object, matching closely what the form submits. This object should contain a userId. Then the controller should create an Article from the submitted object, by getting the User identified by the submitted ID from the database.

Comment: @JB Nizet Thanks a lot buddy, i got "400 error" reason from your comment. Your advice helps,  i'm trying to do something about that. Really thanks!

Comment: @ Onur A when i access http://localhost:8080/XX/articles/addArticle with method GET, method addArticle(ModelMap modelMap) is invoked, then the controller sends physical view (/WEB-INF/jsp/<b>articles/addArticleForm</b>.jsp, this depends on your view resolver) to your browser. If you try to submit form data to controller, this request, with method POST, is just sent to the same address, and it makes method addArticle(Article article) invoked. Hope help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        title: <input type="text" name="title"/><br/>
        author: <select name="author.userId">
                <c:forEach items="${authors}" var="author">
                    <option value="${author.userId}">${author.userName}</option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select>
            <br/>
        content: <input type="text" name="content"/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="add"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

change name of <select> tag from "author" to "author.userId" . That works.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are violating REST principles. Always use version in your endpoint and resource name after that. Example - /api/v1/articles. After that with help of HttpMethods access your resources. Example - If you want to

1.1 add new Article , use POST request to /api/v1/articles
1.2 delete existing Article, use DELETE request to /api/v1/articles/{articleId}
1.3 get one Article, use GET request to /api/v1/articles/{articleId}
1.4 get all Articles, use GET request to /api/v1/articles
1.5 update existing Article, use PUT request to /api/v1/articles/{articleId}

2. Never use your Entity which is going to be persisted in DB for all layers. It`s bad practice to connect Entity with your view, instead you can use DTO.
3. Use @ModelAttribute annotation in your controller layer with same name as in view to handle incoming Article object. Example

   public String addArticle(@ModelAttribute("article") Article article )
4. To add new Article first you need to create endpoint which is returning empty Article object inside of ModelMap. Then you must handle this in your front end(JSP) and for submitting this form follow step 3.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you very much Arman. This is an old project from others, and all i need do is to make it work. And there apparently are some bugs there. About these informal codes, I'd like to say what you tell are really good pieces of advice which really do help. If possible, i 'm trying to reconstruct these codes. Really appreciate for your help!